# Y a-t-il un mot à consonance plus française pour « Sandwich » ?

Tags: anglais, vocabulaire, anglicismes

[D'après Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich#Histoire) :

> Le sandwich, en tant qu'aliment, tient son nom de John Montagu, 4<sup>e</sup> comte de Sandwich.

Et en France, nous utilisons couramment le terme sandwich. Toutefois, ce mot a une très forte consonance anglo-saxonne et je voulais savoir, par curiosité, s'il existait un mot un peu plus français pour désigner un sandwich.

Comment: Merci de m'avoir éclairé sur l'origine du mot. Je m'étais toujours demandé quel était le rapport avec le sable ou les sorcières (qui ne sont pas vraiment appétissants)…

Comment: Juste pour être clair, le mot normal en français (au moins en France) est sandwich. Ce mot est parfaitement français et les autres mots proposés dans les réponses soit sont limités géographiquement, soit désignent un type particulier de sandwich, soit peuvent désigner autre chose qu'un sandwich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le sandwich fait certainement partie de ces derniers échanges linguistiques incessants que la longue histoire franco-britannique a connue ; il représente, en France, une demi baguette de pain tranchée sur sa longueur dans laquelle on peut disposer une grande variété d'aliments.

Les aïeux adeptes du béret, de la baguette sous le bras et de la bouteille de gros rouge qui tache dans le cabas parlent de **casse-croûte** et plus familièrement de **casse-dalle**, car on parlait alors de casser la croûte du pain dans lequel on avait mis une rondelle de saucisson ou autre charcuterie, un morceau de camembert ou d'emmenthal.

Depuis, c'est devenu un mot générique de repas pris dans une cantine, un routier (un restaurant sur les bord des routes destiné aux routiers), un bistro ; il est synonyme de repas pris rapidement, sans toutefois être un fast-food, car on y est servi à table.

En revanche, dans le midi, on parle de **[pan-bagnat](https://www.google.fr/search?q=pan-bagnat&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)**, beaucoup plus élaboré.

Définitions tirées du Nouveau petit Robert.

Comment: Le populaire *casse-croute* ou le plus huppé *encas* me semblent de bonnes traductions de *snack*, mais *sandwich* est quand même plus spécifique. On peut dire *préparer le casse-croute* pour désigner autre chose que des aliments entre deux tranches de pain. Mais ça doit être le meilleur synonyme quand même, je rougis de ne pas y avoir pensé...

Comment: @RomainVALERI Aujourd'hui oui, mais autrefois le pain représentait 80% de la nourriture que l'on pouvait transporter avec soi sans avoir à emporter sa gamelle pour être réchauffée. Le sandwich tire son originalité du pain de mie utilisé, sinon une tranche de pain dans une main, et un bout de fromage dans l'autre (ou une tranche de pain sec frottée d'ail et arrosée d'huile d'olive) permettait vraiment de *casser la croûte*.

Comment: Le sandwich n'est pas limité au pain de mie ou à la baguette. N'importe quel type de pain de n'importe quelle forme s'appelle *sandwich*, du moment qu'il y a deux épaisseurs de pain qui encadrent autre chose.

Answer (score 13):

Je dirais qu'il n'y a pas de mot plus français que "sandwich" pour désigner un sandwich.

Etant donné que :

- le terme est issu d'éponyme (anglo-saxon, certes, mais on ne "traduit" pas les noms propres)
- le terme n'avait pas de synonyme plus ancien (je veux dire qu'on avait évidemment pas inventé le terme *avant* d'inventer l'objet qu'il désigne)
- il a acquis un degré d'usage totalement hégémonique en France
- il n'a pas réellement de synonyme francisé qui ait fait recette, **même après plus de deux siècles d'usage** *(édition : la proposition de cl-r, "casse-croute", est tout de même assez satisfaisante, voir commentaires de sa réponse)*
- la [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sandwich) du CNRTL cite un example datant de 1802...

Il me semble qu'on peut considérer que le terme est aujourd'hui "Français de plein droit". J'ajouterais volontiers "depuis longtemps"...

(Remarque : si ce n'est pas le cas, quel mot peut être dit "français" ? Faut-il n'être issu de rien ? ni même du latin ou de l'indo-européen ?)

Answer (score 4):

Le « sandwich » français désigne habituellement au « submarine sandwich » anglo-saxon.

Le terme « tartine » désigne à la base une tranche de pain garnie. Mais, en Belgique au moins, il s’emploie  également pour désigner de la garniture entre deux tranches de pain, ce qui correspond mieux au « sandwich » générique anglo-saxon.

Par exemple, on dit des enfants qui, le midi à l’école, se nourrissent de sandwichs préparés par leurs parents qu’ils mangent au « dîner tartine » (car, oui, en Belgique, l’on dîne le midi).

Comment: Effectivement, *tartine* peut signifier sandwich, mais c'est strictement belge. En France, une tartine n'a de pain que d'un côté.

Comment: ***dîner*** http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/d%C3%AEner *§A* d’abord premier repas, ensuite repas de mi-journée… Maintenant du soir. Depuis que la soupe [populaire|paysane] n’est plus servie (parfois remplacée par un consommé) le *souper* a disparu du langage hexagonale citadin.

Comment: *tartine* dans ce sens est aussi utilisé dans le Nord de la France, en tout cas ce l'était dans ma jeunesse, certes il y a longtemps, idem pour dîner à midi

Comment: Puisqu'on parle de belgique, notons aussi le "sandwich (mou)" très belge : https://www.delifrance.com/be_fr/sandwich-mou-1.html qui même non-garni est malgré tout un sandwich... Le "mou" vient éventuellement lever l'ambiguité dans les sandwicheries qui proposeraient ce type de pain comme support au lieu de la baguette par exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Même si le terme est plus spécifique que *sandwich*, le plus franchouillard que je connaisse est:

> jambon-beurre

Certes, ça écarte la baguette remplie de pâté, d'emmental ou de thon-mayonnaise, mais ça permet aussi d'exclure tous les paninis, pains briochés ou pains de mie qu'on trouve désormais dans les boutiques franchisées.

Comment: Traduire *sandwich* par *jambon-beurre* me parait aussi juste que de traduire *tool* par *marteau*. Ce n'est plus le même sens...